# Is there a lazy mapM?

Tags: haskell, monads, lazy-evaluation

At first glance I thought these two functions would work the same:

```
firstM _ []     = return Nothing
firstM p (x:xs) = p x >>= \r -> if r then return (Just x) else firstM p xs

firstM' p xs    = fmap listToMaybe (mapM p xs)
```

But they don't. In particular, `firstM` stops as soon as the first `p x` is true. But `firstM'`, because of `mapM`, needs the evaluate the whole list.

Is there a "lazy `mapM`" that enables the second definition, or at least one that doesn't require explicit recursion?

Comment: Do you mean `fmap listToMaybe (filterM p xs)`?

Comment: What monad are you running your two functions in?  (In particular, I suspect part of the answer is "there's no definition of 'lazy mapM' that works for all moands" and part of the answer is "lazy mapM for IO is basically mixing actions and lazy evaluation in precisely the way Haskell is designed to avoid").

Comment: `firstM` and `firstM'` have different types __and__ semantics. The first one is `Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m (Maybe a)`, whereas the latter is `Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m (Maybe b)`. Are you sure about that?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't (can't be) a safe, `Monad`-polymorphic lazy `mapM`. But [the `monad-loops` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.3/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html) contains many lazy monadic variants of various pure functions, and includes `firstM`.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use [`ListT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-t-0.4.5.1/docs/ListT.html), the list monad transformer. This type interleaves side effects and results, so you can peek at the initial element without running the whole computation first.

Here's an example using `ListT`:

```
import Control.Monad
import qualified ListT

firstM :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> m (Maybe a)
firstM p = ListT.head . mfilter p . ListT.fromFoldable
```

(Note that the `ListT` defined in `transformers` and `mtl` is [buggy](https://wiki.haskell.org/ListT_done_right) and should not be used. The version I linked above should be okay, though.)

Answer (score 1):

If there is, I doubt it's called `mapM`.

As I recall, `mapM` is defined in terms of `sequence`:

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> [a] -> m [b]
mapM f = sequence . map f
```

and the whole point of `sequence` is to guarantee that all the side-effects are done before giving you anything.

As opposed to using some alternate `mapM`, you could get away with just using `map` and `sequence`, so you could change the container from `[a]` to `Just a`:

```
firstM p xs = sequence $ listToMaybe (map p xs)
```

or even:

```
firstM p xs = mapM f $ listToMaybe xs
```

Now that `mapM` and `sequence` can operate on generic `Traversable`s, not just lists.

Comment: `firstM'` in the question is probably misleading, since `firstM` actually took the first element that fulfilled the monadic predicate.