# Haskell: Replace mapM in a monad transformer stack to achieve lazy evaluation (no space leaks)

Tags: haskell, monads, lazy-evaluation, monad-transformers

It has already been discussed that `mapM` is inherently not lazy, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270255/is-haskells-mapm-not-lazy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358913/is-mapm-in-haskell-strict-why-does-this-program-get-a-stack-overflow). Now I'm struggling with a variation of this problem where the `mapM` in question is deep inside a monad transformer stack.

Here's a function taken from a concrete, working (but space-leaking) example using LevelDB that I put on [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/mcmayer/57884805528632736d4e3bbc9a74b0af):

```
-- read keys [1..n] from db at DirName and check that the values are correct
doRead :: FilePath -> Int -> IO ()
doRead dirName n = do
    success <- runResourceT $ do
        db <- open dirName defaultOptions{ cacheSize= 2048 }
        let check' = check db def in        -- is an Int -> ResourceT IO Bool
            and <$> mapM check' [1..n]      -- space leak !!!
    putStrLn $ if success then "OK" else "Fail"
```

This function reads the values corresponding to keys `[1..n]` and checks that they are all correct. The troublesome line inside the `ResourceT IO a` monad  is

```
and <$> mapM check' [1..n]
```

One solution would be to use streaming libraries such as `pipes`, `conduit`, etc. But these seem rather heavy and I'm not at all sure how to use them in this situation.

Another path I looked into is `ListT` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950142/is-there-a-lazy-mapm). But the type signatures of `ListT.fromFoldable :: [Bool]->ListT Bool` and `ListT.fold :: (r -> a -> m r) -> r -> t m a -> mr` (where `m`=`IO` and `a`,`r`=`Bool`) do not match the problem at hand.

What is a 'nice' way to get rid of the space leak?

**Update:** Note that this problem has nothing to do with monad transformer stacks! Here's a summary of the proposed solutions:

1) Using `Streaming`:

```
import Streaming
import qualified Streaming.Prelude as S
S.all_ id (S.mapM check' (S.each [1..n]))
```

2) Using `Control.Monad.foldM`:

```
foldM (\a i-> do {b<-check' i; return $! a && b}) True [1..n]
```

3) Using `Control.Monad.Loops.allM`

```
allM check' [1..n]
```

Comment: Besides the answer I gave, what happens if you use plain regular `foldM` from `Control.Monad`? It seems you could avoid materializing the list that way as well.

Comment: I just tried this here: `foldM (\a i-> do {b<-check' i; return $ a && b}) True [1..n]` and it does not remove the space leak.
`foldM`=`foldlM` is also just a sequence of `>>=`, it seems.

Comment: @mcmayer, try `return $! a && b` instead (currently `foldM` is returning a thunk like `((... && True) && True) && True` before evaluating it) .  If that doesn't fix it, I think you are probably misdiagnosing the leak.

Comment: @luqui Yes, `return $! a && b` works indeed! No space leaks.

Answer (score 5):

I know you mention you don't want to use streaming libraries, but your problem seems pretty easy to solve with [*streaming*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.1.4.3) without changing the code too much.

```
import Streaming
import qualified Streaming.Prelude as S
```

We use `each [1..n]` instead of `[1..n]` to get a stream of elements:

```
each :: (Monad m, Foldable f) => f a -> Stream (Of a) m ()
```

> Stream the elements of a pure, foldable container.

(We could also write something like `S.take n $ S.enumFrom 1`).

We use [`S.mapM check'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.1.4.3/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:mapM) instead of `mapM check'`:

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> Stream (Of a) m r -> Stream (Of b) m r
```

> Replace each element of a stream with the result of a monadic action

And then we fold the stream of booleans with [`S.all_ id`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.1.4.3/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:all):

```
all_ :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> Stream (Of a) m r -> m Bool
```

Putting it all together:

```
S.all_ id (S.mapM check' (S.each [1..n]))
```

Not too different from the code you started with, and without the need for any new operator.

Comment: Yes, that does the job!

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is [`allM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.3/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html#v:allM) from the monad-loops package.

Then it would be just `allM check' [1..n]`

(Or if you don't want the import it's a pretty small function to copy.)

Comment: This is the simplest solution so far!